# Delphi Indy error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: openssl, delphi-xe, indy10

I have been using

- Delphi XE
- Indy 10.5.7
- OpenSSL 1.0.2n (https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL).

When I try to execute code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  URL, Str: string;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  URL := 'https://satsis.info/tv/wek/schedule_channel_3_week.html';
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;

  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    try
      IdHTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
      Str := IdHTTP.Get(URL);
      Memo1.Text := Str;
    finally
      SSL.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I get the error:

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

What I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose the problem. An alert means the peer rejected the handshake, but that could happen for any number of reasons. The first one that comes to mind is if the peer requires TLS 1.1 or higher. Indy defaults to TLS 1.0. Try playing with the IOHandler's `SSLVersions` property. Also, 10.5.7 is quite a bit old, the current version is 10.6.2. You might want to consider upgrading.

Comment: Yes with Indy version 10.6.2 the error is not raised. Changing `SSLVersions` property in version 10.5.7 gives nothing.

Comment: another possibility could be SNI, [which 10.6.2 enables](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20160110B.EN.aspx) but 10.5.7 doesn't. Without seeing the actual handshake data, it is really hard to know what is actually happening. You should use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to look at the handshakes of 10.5.7 and 10.6.2 to see what is different between them.